# How can I check if a package is installed (no superuser privileges)?

Tags: package-management

At our university we can get almost any ubuntu package installed we want, but we are not superusers ourselves (we need to request packages being installed).

With some libraries it is not always easy to know whether the package is already installed or not. Is there a simple way/command to check this?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
apt-cache policy <package name>
```

Comment: It's important to know that it supports tab completion in the package name. So it's quite useful even when you don't know the exact package name.

Comment: Shame that still exits with status 0 even if the package is not present. `dpkg -s` does however: https://askubuntu.com/a/1108801/52975

Comment: With [friendlier `apt`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/apt.8.html): `apt policy <package name>` or `apt show <package name>` for more info.

Answer (score 18):

I always just use this from the command line:

```
dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

so the above asks dpkg to list all the installed packages and then I grep for only those that have mysql in the name.

Comment: `dpkg -l "*mysql*"` also works and does not hide the explanatory lines in the output.

Comment: `dpkg -l "*mysql*"` (or `dpkg -l '*mysql*'`) also makes special formatting of the output to fit each package on one line of the terminal window (grep doesn't). And this form allows you to choose the wildcard format (prefixes or suffixes), and whether to use wildcards at all (compared to grep). But grep gives nice coloring.. ))

Comment: This is not correct. `dpkg -l` does not ask dpkg to list all installed packages. The output of `dpkg -l` will also include packages that you installed but then removed. The correct way to do this is by either checking that the first column of the `dpkg -l` output is equal to `ii` or by running: `dpkg-query --showformat '${Status}\n' --show $pkg` which will show `install ok installed` for packages that are actually installed.

Answer (score 7):

One more variant, using aptitude this time:

```
aptitude show <package>
```

Tab completion works here as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can use dselect. It provides non-su read-only access.

Also, `dpkg -s <package name>` provides a lot of details related to a package. Eg"

```
userme:~$ dpkg-query -s sl
Package: sl
Status: unknown ok not-installed
Priority: optional
Section: games
```

Comment: This is also available as just `dpkg -s` .  And conversely, `dpkg-query -l` works just as well as `dpkg -l` or `dpkg --list`

Answer (score 5):

You may use `dpkg-query -s <package> 2>/dev/null | grep -q ^"Status: install ok installed"$`  in scripts, since it returns exit code 1, if the `<package>` is not installed, and 0 if the `<package>` is installed.

Comment: **Be careful**: If `dpkg -s` returns `0`, it doesn't necessarily mean that the package is **fully/correctly** installed. `dpkg -s` also returns `0` if the package is in `half-configured` or in `config-files` state (and I guess also in `half-installed`, but I didn't check that). See [the man page of `dpkg`(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/dpkg.1.html) for further "incomplete" states.

Comment: @Ignitor, good point. My answer was wrong. The package could even be removed, but not purged. So I think you have to examine the output to check, if the package is installed or not.

Comment: I edited the answer. Now it relies on output of dpkg-query. I don't know how portable this solution is; for example, may the text be displayed in another language in some system?

Answer (score 4):

**`dpkg-query --showformat='${db:Status-Status}'`**

This produces a small output string which is unlikely to change and is easy to compare deterministically without `grep`:

```
pkg=hello
status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' "$pkg" 2>&1)"
if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ ! "$status" = installed ]; then
  sudo apt install $pkg
fi
```

The `$? = 0` check is needed because if you've never installed a package before, and after you remove certain packages such as `hello`, `dpkg-query` exits with status 1 and outputs to stderr:

```
dpkg-query: no packages found matching hello
```

instead of outputting `not-installed`. The `2>&1` captures that error message too when it comes preventing it from going to the terminal.

For multiple packages:

```
pkgs='hello certbot'
install=false
for pkg in $pkgs; do
  status="$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' "$pkg" 2>&1)"
  if [ ! $? = 0 ] || [ ! "$status" = installed ]; then
    install=true
    break
  fi
done
if "$install"; then
  sudo apt install $pkgs
fi
```

The possible statuses are documented in `man dpkg-query` as:

```
   n = Not-installed
   c = Config-files
   H = Half-installed
   U = Unpacked
   F = Half-configured
   W = Triggers-awaiting
   t = Triggers-pending
   i = Installed
```

The single letter versions are obtainable with `db:Status-Abbrev`, but they come together with the action and error status, so you get 3 characters and would need to cut it.

So I think it is reliable enough to rely on the uncapitalized statuses (`Config-files` vs `config-files`) not changing instead.

**`dpkg -s` exit status**

This unfortunately doesn't do what most users want:

```
pkgs='qemu-user pandoc'
if ! dpkg -s $pkgs >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  sudo apt-get install $pkgs
fi
```

because for some packages, e.g. `certbot`, doing:

```
sudo apt install certbot
sudo apt remove certbot
```

leaves `certbot` in state `config-files`, which means that config files were left in the machine. And in that state, `dpkg -s` still returns `0`, because the package metadata is still kept around so that those config files can be handled more nicely.

To actually make `dpkg -s` return 1 as desired, `--purge` would be needed:

```
sudo apt remove --purge certbot
```

which actually moves it into `not-installed`/`dpkg-query: no packages found matching`.

Note that only certain packages leave config files behind. A simpler package like `hello` goes directly from `installed` to `not-installed` without `--purge`.

Tested on Ubuntu 20.10.

**Python `apt` package**

There is a pre-installed Python 3 package called `apt` in Ubuntu 18.04 which exposes an Python apt interface!

A script that checks if a package is installed and installs it if not can be seen at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api/17538002#17538002

Here is a copy for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# aptinstall.py

import apt
import sys

pkg_name = "libjs-yui-doc"

cache = apt.cache.Cache()
cache.update()
cache.open()

pkg = cache[pkg_name]
if pkg.is_installed:
    print "{pkg_name} already installed".format(pkg_name=pkg_name)
else:
    pkg.mark_install()

    try:
        cache.commit()
    except Exception, arg:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Sorry, package installation failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg))
```

**Check if an executable is in `PATH` instead**

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/22589429#22589429

**See also**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-an-apt-get-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not-on-linu/54239534#54239534
- [How do I check if a package is installed on my server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423355/how-do-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-on-my-server)

Comment: No. `dpkg -s` also exits with zero if the package is `Status: deinstall ok config-files`. To try this out yourself, run `dpkg -l` on your system and pass a package to `dpkg -s` which has an `rc` in the first column of your `dpkg -l` output. Even though the package is not installed, `dpkg -s` will exit with success.

Comment: @josch I have discussed possibly related issues further at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-an-apt-get-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not-on-linu/54239534#54239534 BTW. I don't have a perfect solution for it yet.

Comment: Why are the solutions that use `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' ...` not perfect in your opinion?

Comment: @josch have they clearly documented that the exact string output is a stable API? Just cautious since `install ok installed` is a bit long to grep for. I haven't really extensively researched this though.

Comment: But true, `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}'` does seem decent, outputs only `installed`

Comment: `${Status}` gives you the plain value of the `Status` field from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. If you have dpkg 1.17.11 or later, then yes `${db:Status-Status}` gives you just what you want without the "eflag" or the "want". About stability: this didn't change since 1995. Is that stable enough for you? Proof: https://git.hadrons.org/cgit/debian/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/lib/parsehelp.c?id=1b80fb16c22db72457d7a456ffbf1f70a8dfc0a5#n77 As for the documentation: just do `man dpkg` and look into the section `INFORMATION ABOUT PACKAGES` all field values like `installed` are documented there.

Comment: @josch thanks for that link, yes, those strings seem to be quite embedded everywhere, should be fine to rely on them

Answer (score 2):

**Simpler solution:**

There is now an `apt list` command that lists installed packages.  You can also search for a specific package with

```
apt list <package>
```

See `man apt` for more information.

Comment: And `apt show` for more details

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the status printed by `dpkg -l`, example :

```bash
$ dpkg -l firefox-esr vim winff
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-=============================================================================
hi  firefox-esr                          52.9.0esr+build2-0ubunt amd64                   Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
ii  vim                                  2:8.1.1198-0york0~14.04 amd64                   Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor
rc  winff                                1.5.3-3                 all                     graphical video and audio batch converter using ffmpeg or avconv
```

Here both `vim` and `firefox-esr` are installed, therefore you can type :

```bash
$ dpkg -l firefox-esr | grep -q ^.i && echo This package is installed. || echo This package is NOT installed.
This package is installed.
$ dpkg -l vim | grep -q ^.i && echo This package is installed. || echo This package is NOT installed.
This package is installed.
$ dpkg -l winff | grep -q ^.i && echo This package is installed. || echo This package is NOT installed.
This package is NOT installed.
```

Answer (score -1):

Example to use specific value as var in shell scripts (eg `test.sh`)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
PACKAGE="${1}"
INSTALLED=$(dpkg -l | grep ${PACKAGE} >/dev/null && echo "yes" || echo "no")

echo "${PACKAGE} is installed ... ${INSTALLED}"
```

Make it executable and go start with:

```
test.sh openssh-server
```

Or do whatever you want with in your scripts

Comment: This is incorrect. `dpkg -l` will also list packages that you once installed but then removed. Also, grepping `dpkg -l` output as you did will also match on all the text in the package descriptions. The right way is to use `dpkg-query -W --showformat='${db:Status-Status}' $package`.