# How to test if package is installed?

Tags: installation, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check if a package is installed (no superuser privileges)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2943/how-can-i-check-if-a-package-is-installed-no-superuser-privileges)

I want a shell script method to test/report if a package is installed. I don't need details, only a yes/no.

I've come up with this method. Is there a more direct way?

```
is_installed=0
test_installed=( `apt-cache policy domy-ce | grep Installed: ` )
[ ! "${test_installed[1]}" == "(none)" ] && is_installed=1
```

Comment: This post should help you-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not

Comment: Thanks saji89. The apparent duplicate gives accurate results with Debian registered packages, the results are unreliable on Ubuntu PPA packages. With packages that are registered on the host but not installed, dpkg's returncode is zero [0].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the output of
   `dpkg -s <packagename>`   or  `dpkg-query -l <packagename>`

in your script for the purpose.
Courtesy:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298066/check-if-a-package-is-installed-and-then-install-it-if-its-not

e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh

for P; do
    dpkg -s "$P" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo "$P is installed."
    } || {
        echo "$P is not installed."
    }
done
```

Usage: `script.sh package1 package2 .... packageN`

Courtesy:https://stackoverflow.com/a/10594734/749232

Comment: If a package is installed then removed, then `dpkg -s` still exits with a 0 status! See http://askubuntu.com/a/395278/165556