# Did I install LAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 server.  While installing I asked it to install LAMP.  But how do I tell if it is working?   I tried http://192.168.0.20 which is my server, from a web browser on my network. I get the message this website is unavailable.

So what do I type on my server to see if Lamp WAS installed and running?  Then I want to see if MySQL was installed, then PHP and phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if a package is installed (no superuser privileges)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/2943/216503)

Answer (score 1):

You did check to see if it was working and got your answer.

Log into the machine `ssh <user>@192.168.0.20` and execute:

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

This is for the meta-package of a basic LAMP.  Any package required, but not installed will be installed.

If all is successful , you can open your browser to `192.168.0.20` and you will see the **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page**

If you are not successful you will know where the fault lies.